# New Jobs Bug: Getting Json instead of an HTML page while updating job status

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I tried updating my job status to from `I’m still Open, but not actively looking` to `Actively looking right now` by clicking on `Update Status` button on [Jobs home page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs). and got this and thought of reporting it. I haven't found the same bug reported already (Yes, I have searched).

[image: Bug screenshot]

I am using Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m (64-bit) on Windows 8.1 64 bit Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix was pushed to prod earlier today. Thanks for the report!